# Java EE 7 Webservices on Wildfly - JSON issue

Tags: java, json, web-services, wildfly-10

I've created a simple webservice to `@GET` data from given `@Path`. While using `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` everything works properly, I can see the XML output, but while changing `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML` into `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` this issue appears:

> Context Path:/bms
>
> Servlet Path:/resources
>
> Path Info:/actualvalue
>
> Query String:null
>
> Stack Trace
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: RESTEASY003880: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers

I use `org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-7.0:1.0.3-Final` provided by `Wildfly 10`

[edit]

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(false)
@Table(name = "tblActualValueFloat")
@XmlRootElement(name = "tblActualValueFloat")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ActualValueFloat extends AbstractModel {

        /*^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^*/
        @Id
        @Column(name = "PointSliceID")
        @XmlElement(name = "PointSliceID", required = false, type = Integer.class)
        private Integer id;
        @Column(name = "ActualValue")
        @XmlElement(name = "ActualValue", required = false, type = Double.class)
        private Double value;
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "UTCDateTime")
        @XmlElement(name = "UTCDateTime", required = false, type = Date.class)
        private Date date;
        //setters and getters and equals
}
```

[edit2]

**Okay, I see that this works with Glassfish 4.1, but not with Wildfly 10.. Any clues how to avoid this by using provided Java EE Web Services API?**

Comment: These dependencies should be enough: `javax:javaee-web-api:7.0` and `javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api` (maven scope = `provided` for both). You don't need the jboss spec dependency.

Comment: @assylias Modified and same issue :(

Comment: what is the return type of the @GET method?

Comment: `List<Entity> returnedList`, please see edited post :)

Comment: If I create a brand new project with the dependencies I described above and [this simple class](http://pastebin.com/1bQypNVN) - I get a correct output. Maybe try with that class to see if it works to help identify the cause of the issue.

Comment: @assylias Same issue... I created new class named `A` and I see that class `A` must contain no-arg public constructor, and must contain `@XmlRootElement`, thank you for any help :)

Comment: Okay, I see that this works with Glassfish 4.1, but not with Wildfly 10..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have researched that my **org.jboss.weld.osgi.examples:weld-osgi-web-fwk:1.2.0.Beta1** with a filter to add CORS Headers, contained **org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs**, so I have excluded that and now it works properly even on Wildfly 10

Answer (score 1):

@Rafcik I got this error when I excluded the org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:

```
A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<java.lang.String>, and MIME media type application/json was not found.
The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
```

I fixed the error "Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers" by adding the following initializing code:

```
ResteasyProviderFactory factory = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();
ResteasyProviderFactory.pushContext(javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers.class, factory);
ResteasyClientBuilder resteasyClientBuilder = new
ResteasyClientBuilder().providerFactory(factory);
ResteasyClient client = resteasyClientBuilder.build();
```